# C# update statement not updating when update button clicked

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

i am creating c# project so far insert and delete buttons are working but when i hit update button it gives data has not been updated and i cant see what is wrong with my code please help

```
public bool Update(Classre c)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);

    try
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE Class SET ClassName=@ClassName,ClassLevel=@ClassLevel WHERE ClassID=@ClassID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassName", c.ClassName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassLevel", c.ClassLevel);
        conn.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            isSuccess = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return isSuccess;
}
```

and this is my update button code where i call the class that holds my update code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c.ClassID = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); 
    c.ClassName = textBox2.Text;
    c.ClassLevel = comboBox1.Text;

    bool success = c.Update(c);
    if (success == true)
    {
       // label4.Text = "Data Has been updated";
        MessageBox.Show("Data Has been updated");
        DataTable dt = c.Select();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
    else
    {
        //label4.Text = "Data Has not been updated";
        MessageBox.Show("Data Has not been updated");

    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add a parameter value for @ClassID

Comment: Why do you add a try/catch and in your catch block you do nothing? This is a fine way to loose your hairs. Searching for an error but hiding the error

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get rid of that empty catch. That is an anti-pattern I call try/squelch. It captures any errors and ignores them. You also should look into the USING statement, you need to dispose of your objects and you are not currently doing that.

Comment: You might also want to take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @ADyson you are right ur answer worked for me and other thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a stored procedure instead of pass through sql but you could greatly simplify this. As stated above your try/catch is worse than not having one because it squelches the error.

```
public bool Update(Classre c)
{
    USING(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring))
    {
        string sql = "UPDATE Class SET ClassName = @ClassName, ClassLevel = @ClassLevel WHERE ClassID = @ClassID";

        USING(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClassName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4000).Value = c.ClassName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClassLevel", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c.ClassLevel;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClassID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c.ClassID;
            conn.Open();
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return rows > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: stored procedure is hard to track with source control. I prefer sql in code too.

Comment: SQL in code is generally a terrible idea. We have better ways of doing data access in this century than an SQL string in a button click handler

Comment: @Steve I worked on a project with several hundred stored procedures. Managing them in source code was no issue, you just store them in files and make the changes to the files using a SQL editor, then execute them when you want to apply them to the db. Or you can use a DB project in Visual Studio. What makes you think it's hard to do? SQL within code is hard to unit test, and makes sharing SQL-based logic between different apps and services hard (if that's the architecture, these days you would probably say put an API in front of it anyway).